# Many three phase Identical motors connected in parallel but have different speed why?

Tags: power-electronics, electrical, electricity

My teacher asked me a question that many identical three phase motors are connected in parallel with same rating and also mechanically  they are same but there is 2 motors which was running at slow speed as compared to others and there is only a 2V voltage drop in these two motors but there is a large change in its speed, why?

Comment: Consider each motor and it's surroundings a a "system". Is there any difference between the various systems ? In the real world will each "system" be absolutely identical? If not, what type of differences are there likely to be?

Comment: What if the had the same HP rating so they were interpreted as mechanicaly the same But one had 5 poles and run half as fast as the 2 pole motor .

Comment: Kindly read my question carefully please i was define everything in it but i did not find its answer.

Comment: @John Son, can please elaborate the 2V voltage drop? Across what?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is missing critical detail and the asker responds to requests to provide it only by reposting the question and demanding that people "read carefully"

Comment: "2V voltage drop" needs clarification. Betting on almost-seized bearings.

Comment: I think you are not telling us something. This sounds like a real setup and if it is you need to tell us because you word it as if it was a hypothetical question from your teacher. In real setups, nothing is identical and there can be errors and damage. I think this is not a made-up hypothetical example because you say there are "many" motors , but then pick out two motors specifically. If a theoretical example says "many" motors then there is no known, exact number of motors, but then it is very strange to talk about two motors specifically instead of just one behaving differently.

Comment: I quite agree, OP has no more info than this, and is saying it is complete because it's a homework/test question, which OP presumes to be complete. Because it would be unfair homework if it was not.  And thus is annoyed that we don't get it. (And also frustrated for not knowing the material).

Comment: My teacher said, its a practical example of industry and he saw it thats why he asked.

Comment: In industry, people dealing with problems have much more information to work with. They are either familiar with the motors and the driven equipment or they immediately inspect the installation. I can think of at east two additional possibilities of the source of this problem that someone with knowledge of the installation would either immediately rule out or investigate based on information that would be immediately available to someone familiar with the installation.

Answer (score 1):

AC motors have poles on the stator that act with poles (temporary
magnetization) in the rotor to make a torque.   A permanent magnet stepper motor may
have dozens of poles, and rotate a small fraction of a turn per cycle,
but more common induction motors turn one or one half turn per AC cycle, which
means a 60 Hz motor may be 3600 rpm or 1800 rpm.
Synchronous motors run at exact speeds, but due to stator magnetization slippage,
the nominal speed for a common induction motor is less, perhaps 3450 rpm or 1725 rpm, at rated torque/horsepower delivered.

The synchronous speed of a 60 Hz AC motor can be 3600, 2400, 1800,
or 1440 rpm depending if it has two, three, four, or 5 "poles" (pole pairs). A three-phase induction motor, not fully synchronous,
will be slightly slower depending on the magnetic hysteresis
property of the rotor, and on loading.

Comment: But there is only 2 motors which is running at slow speed and all are (3 phase) induction motors. The all other motors was running at their desired speed except 2 motors.

Comment: Kindly read my question carefully then answer me thanks.

Comment: @JohnSon Unless the motors are stalled or overloaded, the speed of an AC motor has a small range of speed, set by the poles and AC frequency and not 'the voltage'.  What speeds, exactly, do you see?  Are the slow motors getting hot?

Comment: My teacher asked me a question that many identical three phase motors are connected in parallel with same rating and also mechanically they are same but there is 2 motors which was running at slow speed as compared to others and there is only a 2V voltage drop in these two motors but there is a large change in its speed, why? This is my question dear

Comment: @John Son - so all motors are IDENTICAL ? Can you confirm that?

Comment: @VillageTech and others: Why not read the question? *My teacher asked me a question that many **identical** three phase motors are connected in parallel with **same** rating and also mechanically they are **same***.

Comment: Ok, just asking, don't worry ;)

Comment: The last sentence in this answer reduces its quality considerably. AC motors are either synchronous or not synchronous (asynchronous). Induction motors are asynchronous. "Not fully synchronous" is not a good way to describe that. The slower speed of an induction motor is the synchronous speed of the magnetic fields minus slip. Slip is due to the need for a speed differential to induce current in the rotor. It does most assuredly not depend on magnetic hysteresis.

Comment: Yes all are equal